# Simulating of GBM

Tags: brownian-motion, monte-carlo, simulation

I have a question regarding the simulation of a GBM. I have found similar questions here but nothing which takes reference to my specific problem:

Given a GBM of the form

$dS(t) = \mu S(t) dt + \sigma S(t) dW(t)$

it is clear that this SDE has a closed form solution in

$S(t) = S(0) exp ([\mu - \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2]t + \sigma W(t))$

for a given $S(0)$.

Now, I have found sources claiming that in order to simulate the whole trajectory of the GBM, one needs to convert it to its discrete form (e.g., a similar question here or Iacus: "Simulation and Inference for Stochastic Differential Equations", 62f.). Yet, in Glasserman: "Monte Carlo Methods in Fin. Eng.", p. 94, I find that

$S(t_{i+1}) = S(t_i) exp ([\mu - \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2](t_{i+1}-t_i) + \sigma\sqrt{t_{i+1}-t_i} Z_{i+1})$

where $i=0,1,\cdots, n-1$ and $Z_1,Z_2,\cdots,Z_n$ are independent standard normals is an exact method (i.e., has no apprximation error from discretization).

I really don't understand what the difference between the two is, or put differently, if the exact method lets me simulate the whole trajectory, why would I bother converting it to the discrete form?

Maybe I'm just not seeing the point here but I'm really confused and grateful for any help!

Answer (score 0):

In order to simulate any process, you first have to discretize it in order for your machine to work. The thing is that sometimes you don't think about this explicitly but rather accept it implicitly.

So the discretization happens in terms of the 
\begin{eqnarray}
n = \frac{T}{\Delta t} \text{,}
\end{eqnarray}
where $\Delta t$ represents the stepwise, $n$ represents the number of steps and $T$ represents the final time step.

Please read the [wiki on Brownian motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_motion) , [discretization](https://www.google.com/search?q=discretization&rlz=1C1NDCM_enZA861ZA861&oq=discretization&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j35i39j0l6.2822j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and the [wiki on adaptive step sizes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_step_size).

The following example from [scipy cookbook](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/BrownianMotion.html) also illustrates what I am saying.

```
    #https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/BrownianMotion.html
    from math import sqrt
    from scipy.stats import norm
    import numpy as np


def brownian(x0, n, dt, delta, out=None):
    """
    Generate an instance of Brownian motion (i.e. the Wiener process):

        X(t) = X(0) + N(0, delta**2 * t; 0, t)

    where N(a,b; t0, t1) is a normally distributed random variable with mean a and
    variance b.  The parameters t0 and t1 make explicit the statistical
    independence of N on different time intervals; that is, if [t0, t1) and
    [t2, t3) are disjoint intervals, then N(a, b; t0, t1) and N(a, b; t2, t3)
    are independent.

    Written as an iteration scheme,

        X(t + dt) = X(t) + N(0, delta**2 * dt; t, t+dt)

    """
    x0 = np.asarray(x0)

    # For each element of x0, generate a sample of n numbers from a
    # normal distribution.
    r = norm.rvs(size=x0.shape + (n,), scale=delta*sqrt(dt))

    # If `out` was not given, create an output array.
    if out is None:
        out = np.empty(r.shape)

    # This computes the Brownian motion by forming the cumulative sum of
    # the random samples. 
    np.cumsum(r, axis=-1, out=out)

    # Add the initial condition.
    out += np.expand_dims(x0, axis=-1)

    return out
```

Which we then use as

```
import numpy
from pylab import plot, show, grid, xlabel, ylabel

# The Wiener process parameter.
delta = 2
# Total time.
T = 10.0
# Number of steps.
N = 500
# Time step size
dt = T/N
# Number of realizations to generate.
m = 20
# Create an empty array to store the realizations.
x = numpy.empty((m,N+1))
# Initial values of x.
x[:, 0] = 50

brownian(x[:,0], N, dt, delta, out=x[:,1:])

t = numpy.linspace(0.0, N*dt, N+1)
for k in range(m):
    plot(t, x[k])
xlabel('t', fontsize=16)
ylabel('x', fontsize=16)
grid(True)
show()
```

Note: Sorry can't upload pics yet. I don't have enough rep.